# Ubuntu 21.04 Intermittently no Wi-Fi adapter found

Tags: networking, iwlwifi, 21.04

I have been looking through askubuntu for similar issues and have found some useful tips but nothing appears to quite match the problem I am having since upgrading to Ubuntu 21.04 and I am actually wondering if it may be a hardware issue.

Since the upgrade, my laptop's (ThinkPad T14s) wifi adapter cannot be found most of the time, `rfkill` only shows the bluetooth device and the output of `lspci -knn | grep -i network -A 3` is empty.
Sometimes however, when I start up the laptop, the wifi adapter is found. And `lspci -knn | grep -i network -A 3` produces:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:0080]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Yesterday, after a restart, I used my wifi connection for a while (~15 minutes) before it dropped out with the adapter disappearing -- this happened without the computer going to sleep. A restart did not solve the issue. And over the last few restarts, the adapter did not reappear. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the output of following commands? `sudo lshw -C network` and `rfkill list`

Comment: Writing this from my desktop, it's a bit complicated to post the output since I can't go online. I need to find a USB drive. But, in brief, `rfkill list` only shows a bluetooth adapter and `sudo lshw -C network` only lists a Realtek gigabit ethernet controller. This is of course with the wifi not working, which seems to be happening around 90% of the time I restart.

Comment: `sudo lshw -C network` should list your WiFi adapter. Otherwise it might be a hardware issue.

Comment: There is only one entry for the ethernet controller listed right now. I was suspecting it could be a hardware issue, it is just strange that the issue coincided with the ubuntu upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

It was a hardware hardware issue -- from the evidence so far. I opened up the laptop (after disabling the battery via the bios), disconnected the cables from the wifi adapter, took the adapter out and reconnected everything again. Now the wifi is working and has survived 3 restarts of the system.

Thanks @Akash for pointing me in this direction, I would have looked for software solutions for quite a while longer.

PS: After the reconnection, `sudo lshw -C network` also shows the adapter again:

```
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 1a
       serial: a8:7e:ea:ba:87:3b
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.11.0-16-generic firmware=59.601f3a66.0 cc-a0-59.ucode ip=192.168.1.102 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:88 memory:fd600000-fd603fff
```